# Right align line numbers with linum-mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like that my `linum-mode` numbering is right aligned. The closest thing I've found is on emacswiki, but it doesn't work - it seems to *left align* the digits instead of *right align* it. [The snippet is found here](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LineNumbers#toc6). Sorry for the horrible indenting, lisp is pretty alien to me :)

```
(setq linum-format                               
      (lambda (line)                                    
    (propertize                                  
     (format                                 
      (let                                   
      ((w (length (number-to-string (count-lines (point-min)         
                             (point-max))))))    
    (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d ")) line) 'face 'linum)))
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Customize variable linum-format, for example to align on the right on 7 characters :

```
(custom-set-variables '(linum-format (quote "%7d")))
```

Comment: I would have liked this a lot more if it'd been dynamically done, but once a file passes 1000 lines it doesn't matter anyways. Thanks! :) I settled for `%4d`.

Answer (score 21):

You can just use the value `'dynamic` so you don't have to choose an arbitrary amount of padding:

```
(custom-set-variables '(linum-format 'dynamic))
```

Or you can also customize it with: `M-x customize-variable RET linum-format`

Also, @asmeurer asked how to still add a space after the number with `dynamic`. There is no easy way to do that, but it can be accomplished using `defadvice` around the `linum-update-window` function that I adapted from the code for `dynamic` that is already in that function:

```
(defadvice linum-update-window (around linum-dynamic activate)
  (let* ((w (length (number-to-string
                     (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))))
         (linum-format (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d ")))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Thanks. You can also change this with `M-x customize`.

Comment: How can you use use dynamic and still add a space after the number? I'm sure it's straight-forward, but I'm still pretty new to lisp.

Comment: @asmeurer I updated my answer to show how to use `defadvice` to still add a space after the number. And yes, you can use `customize` which is related to `custom-set-variables`.

Answer (score 1):

In 2022, for Emacs 28.1, the command is:

```lisp
(setq linum-format 'dynamic)
```

Answer (score -3):

change the linum.el and byte-compile-file to .elc.

for emacs 23.3

line 143 of linum.el

```
                  (concat "%" (number-to-string w) "d" " | ")))))
```

I change the default fort to "xxx | ".

Comment: Changing the code directly is not a good long-term solution unless you are going to submit a patch upstream that you think will be accepted, otherwise when your emacs installation is upgraded you are going to lose those changes. Instead, in your `init.el` file you can add `defadvice` for the `linum-update-window` function, as the [latest edits to my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8470136/462302) shows how to do.